# Найти все повторяющиеся значения в csv-файле с помощью dask

Tags: python, csv

Использую dask для чтения большого (4 гб) csv-файла. Нужно найти в нем все одинаковые значения в одной из колонок. В pandas для этого есть duplicted(), а в dask нет ничего. Как можно реализовать такую функцию?

Comment: Попробуйте создать свою функцию - https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-best-practices.html#:~:text=at%20providing%20support.-,Build%20your%20own%20Operations,-%C2%B6

Comment: @Сергей я даже не представляю, как такую функцию можно реализовать